# Setting Windows 7 to active partition

Tags: windows, grub

Currently, I have grub as my bootloader.  Windows runs on a slave hard drive and Ubuntu is on the master.

I need to set Windows to be the active partition because it requires this for the installing of Windows 7 Service pack 1.

Now, simply unplugging the master hard drive will not work because the windows drive does not have a bootloader of it's own, so the computer just sits idle.

My question is, is it possible to make windows and Ubuntu both masters with separate bootloaders or is it possible to somehow give priority to the Windows partition with Grub for the time being?

Comment: What is a slave harddrive? Is this about two physical hardrives, a master and slave drive on a IDE/ATA cable?

Comment: Is your question, “How do I change the default operating system for grub to boot?”

Answer (score 0):

Add theses 2 lines to `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

you will have to replace a line like

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

Now run `update-grub` as root e.g. `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be also looked into by changing the priority order in your BIOS making your windows boot loader as a top option. This makes your windows boot media as master.